# Scroll DataList to an object

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I've a DataList with Weeknumber and the weekly projects. The DataList (made as table with horizontal repeat driection) has a width of 7000px.

The DIV around is 1000px of width, with a horizontal scrollbar.

I need to scroll the div to the actual week a column (id of td is weeknumber in Format YYYYWW). How can I achieve this?

I tried javascript scrollintoview(id), but it only jumps for a short moment...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="divWochen">
        <asp:DataList ID="dgWochen" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdWoche" id="<%# Eval("Wochennummer") %>"><%# Eval("Woche") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdProjekte"><%# Eval("Projekte") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdFreieMitarbeiter">Frei:<br /><%# Eval("Freie Mitarbeiter") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnHeute" runat="server" Text="Aktuelle Woche" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Button Event:

```
btnHeute.CommandArgument = AktuelleWochennummer.ToString();
    btnHeute.OnClientClick = "ScrollInAktuelleWoche(" + AktuelleWochennummer.ToString() + ")";
```

Javascript:

```
function ScrollInAktuelleWoche(InterneWochennummer) {
    var element = document.getElementById(InterneWochennummer);
    element.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```